# How can I change the background color of a Mac app's view in code with Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, nsview

I'm working on a single-view Mac application and I want to change the background color programmatically. How do I do it?

Comment: Make outlet of the view from storyboard to the class and access that view outlet's backgroundcolor proprty and set some color there.

Comment: @unexpectedNil I didn't really understand anything you said, sorry. Please explain to a noobie like me haha.

Answer (score 14):

Put this code in the `viewDidLoad()` function for your main `NSViewController`. That's `ViewController.swift` in the Cocoa Application template.

```
// tell the controller's view to use a CALayer as its backing store
view.wantsLayer = true
// change the background color of the layer
view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

Replace red with your color of choice, obviously. For RGBA you can use `CGColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` instead of NSColor. It accepts `CGFloat` values from 0 to 1, so for example lime green would be: `CGColor(red: 50/255, green: 205/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)`

Once you've set [`view.wantsLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483695-wantslayer), you can change the color without setting it again.

Comment: This worked great. But one more thing, how would I use a hex/rgba code? @Robert

Comment: For RGBA you can use `CGColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` instead of NSColor. It accepts CGFloat values from 0 to 1, so for example lime green would be: `CGColor(red: 50/255, green: 205/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)`

Comment: I get an expected declaration error when trying to compile. Coming from the view.wantslayer variable

Comment: No such method as wantsLayer

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are trying to change the background property on the **view**, not the view **controller**. View controllers don't have backgrounds since they don't show anything, but they have views that do:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor;
}
```

That will turn the background color of the main view of the viewcontroller to red.

Comment: Do we really need a `;` after `NSColor.red.cgColor`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the extension to change the background color of MacOS.

```
extension NSViewController{
    

    func setBackgroundColor(_ color : NSColor, alpha : CGFloat){
        
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        view.alphaValue = alpha
    }
}
```